# An overheard gang meeting, a double agent, and a murder

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I was walking home late last night and heard raised voices coming from a boarded up old warehouse. I stopped, out of sight, to listen...

> *[When I started eavesdropping, the conversation was already under way...]*
>
> **Gangster 1**: -infiltrator in our midst, and I know who it is... *[dramatic pause]* ...It's you isn't it!
>   **Gangster 2**: Me?
>   **G1**: What? No... him.
>   **Gangster 3**: That's ridiculous! I'm no traitor! How do we know it's not you?!
>   **G2**: It's not me!
>   **G3**: No... him... *[under breath]* ...idiot.
>   **G1**: That doesn't even make sense. I'm the most prolific amongst us. When would I even have the chance to work for the opposition?
>   **G3**: What do you mean? I'm in every day!
>   **Gangster 4**: *[to himself]* Me too, but you don't hear me harping on...
>   **G3**: *[continuing]* Not to mention I saw you with your ex last week on my way out of here... And I won't mention who I saw him hanging out with *again* yesterday...
>   **G2**: We weren't hanging out! I was just stuck behind him in a queue!
>   **Gangster 5**: Hey, we all fraternize with the enemy now and then... It's necessary to meet our goals... But this is different. From what I hear, half the time you act like you *are* one of them!
>
> *[A street sweeper drove slowly by, so I missed a little of the conversation...]*
>
> **G3**: It's a set up! Think about it... Who would gain the most from seeing me dead? ...I would!
>   **Gangster 6**: 'strue, but 'e would too...
>   **G1**: Sure, he occasionally fills in for me, but he could practically replace you!
>   **G2**: No he couldn't!
>   **G6/G1/G3**: Would you shut up!
>   **G4**: Geez settle down guys, what's with all the yelling?
>   **G1**: Because no one was talking to you!
>   **G4**: Ahh... Gotcha...
>
> *[A crowd of drunken revellers stumbled by and as I slipped into an alley to remain unseen, I missed another few minutes of the argument...]*
>
> **G1**: Gimme one good reason why I shouldn't kill you right now!
>   **G2**: I didn't do anything wrong!
>   **G3**: Wait... Who are we talking about now?
>   **G1**: You!
>   **G2**: Oh...
>   **G5**: Why?
>   **G1**: Yes!
>
> *[From here things escalated rapidly, and when gunshots were fired, I made a run for it...]*

I went to the police but when they visited the scene, the gang was gone, and everything had already been cleaned. They said there wasn't enough to go on unless I could identify the victim and the perpetrators.

**Who was the gang?**
**Which member was killed?**
**Why were they killed?**

**Bonus**: What was the name of each gangster?

Comment: Brilliant puzzle.

Comment: And congrats on your Trusted Usership! You and Aggie are right next to each other in the rep rankings now ;-)

Comment: Found this by accident.  I absolutely LOVE this puzzle, Alconja!

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The gang was the notorious

> Vowel Syndicate!

The victim was

> Y

because

> he was a double agent for the Vowel Syndicate's chief rivals, the Consonant Guild!

The gangsters are, I believe:

> 1: e ("most prolific")
> 2: u (every time someone says "you" he thinks they're talking to him, also was stuck behind "Q")
> 3: y (is in every "day", is the one that seems to be the accused)
> 4: a (is also in every "day")
> 5: o (responds to gangster 2 saying "oh" near the end)
> 6: i (responds to gangster 3 saying "I" would gain the most from seeing "Y" dead)

Comment: I'd also like to note that G2 even mentions a **queue**.

Comment: How did you get the syndicate and guild parts?