# The friends dilemma

Tags: cipher, cryptic-clues

So, some of my RL friends think that I am a mean, arrogant, know-it-all jerk. So, I decided to prove them right. I gave them a note, and told them that it contained something related to my favourite movie. Incidentally, not one of them knew my favourite movie. So, with a smug smile on my face, I handed them the note. It read

> “zhr rngpng b vgfvhgbc “ – Now, don’t worry, I will provide you with some hints as to how this is to be solved. You need to be observant though.
>   The 5 membered-syndicate are dangerous and efficient as well.
>   You see sometimes the unlucky one can prove to be useful.
>   One who can really solve this will reserve the right to be a true and trustworthy friend of mine.
>   And One more- The wise try to speak that which is dead.

**Can you find out my favourite movie?**

HINT 1:

> (5,9) (5,5) (1,1) and nothing in the last.

<sub>Note- the code can be solved by following the instructions in the order that is mentioned. Do not jumble up the order. And each line is a clue as to how to solve the cipher.</sub>

Comment: This for the fortnightly challenge?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Not sure, if we can consider cipher and cryptic-clues as unconventional...

Comment: [5 membered syndicate](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17862/an-overheard-gang-meeting-a-double-agent-and-a-murder)

Comment: "You see sometimes the unlucky one can prove to be useful." Unlucky = 13? ROT13 perhaps.

Comment: Do the spaces between the cipher text remain in the solution?

Comment: @Sid Is the [tag:cryptic-clues] tag definitely appropriate here?  Read the tag wiki carefully.  If not, it's misleading.

Comment: @DanRussell I am a bit torn on that. Because, these are not obvious clues but you also don't see it in crosswords.

Comment: @Sid I mean, very specifically, do they conform to [these standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#Types_of_cryptic_clues)? If they're not the very clearly defined types of wordplay referred to there, we should probably remove that tag.

Comment: @DanRussell Well, one of the clues matches the tags but I don't think the rest of them do...

Comment: Downvoter, Any reason why you would do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have it!

The message means

> "you couldn't handle the truth"

which would seem to indicate that your favorite movie is

> *A Few Good Men* (in which "you can't handle the truth!")

---

Thought process, building off Kevin Rock's and Beastly Gerbil's ideas:

The "five-membered syndicate" are probably

> the five vowels, A E I O U, in reference to a previous Puzzling.SE question

The "unlucky one" could be

> the unlucky number 13 = ROT-13 cipher.
>  Applying this to the ciphertext gives the extremely vowel-heavy "mue eatcat o itsiutop".
>  However, in the puzzle about the vowels, the "unlucky" victim is Y.

"True and trustworthy friend"

> TODO

"Speak that which is dead" could

> refer to Latin, the most famous dead language.
>  A E I O U in ROT-13 are N R V B H. Adding these into the ROT-13'd text can create some valid Latin words: mue → muner[a] "duty", eat → erat "was", for example. But this is a bit of a stretch.

Unusual features of the text:

> There's a space after the ciphertext but within the quotes.
>  The second line mentions the "5 membered-syndicate", not the "5-membered syndicate".
>  The last line has an incorrect - (hyphen) instead of an – (en-dash). This wouldn't normally be notable, but there is a proper en-dash in the first line.
>  The last line also has an extra capitalized O.
>  The two "Ones" likely mean a number somehow, but this could be 2, 11, 7 (5+1+1)...

Regarding the first hint (interpretation debunked by OP):

> In a cryptic crossword, (3, 4) would be "a three-letter word followed by a four-letter word". My guess is that the 5-membered syndicate clue gives XXXXX XXXXXXXXX, the unlucky one gives XXXXX XXXXX, the true and trustworthy friend gives X, and that which is dead indicates how all those words should be put together or interpreted.
>  We also know that one and only one of the first three clues fits the strict definition of a cryptic, due to the tag discussion on the question. None seem to contain the usual clue words, however.

Regarding the first hint (new hypothesis):

> As Lukas Rotter pointed out, 1, 5, and 9 are the indices of A, E, and I in the alphabet (N, R, V in ROT13). So let's add these in.
>  *murev eratcart non itsiutop*?
>  These look like reversed words! *potuisti non tractare verum*
>  *Potuisti* is "you were able", *non* is "not", *tractare* is "to handle", *verum* is "a true thing".
>  So perhaps: "you couldn't handle the truth"? This is stretching the meaning of *verum* ("truth" would really be *veritas*), but it fits the theme of a famous movie reference.

Comment: The unusual features are just typos... But you have all the clues except the friends part... there is another word in that line not the one that you mentioned... and your interpretation of the hint is wrong...

Comment: If A=1 & Z=26, "1", "5" and "9" would all be vowels. Might just be stylistic, though.

Comment: Lukas Rotter has got the idea....

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer:** 
5 membered syndicate

> As mentioned by @BeastlyGerbil, the 5 membered syndicate most likely indicates that vowels need to be added in.

You see sometimes the unlucky one can prove to be useful.

> I'm thinking the unluckly one is probably thirteen. This leads me to using a rot-13. (@Dan Russell commented as I was posting)

The Text So Far:

> mue eatcat o itsiutop
> (Note: Not sure how/where to add vowels before the rotation)
>  Might be important that aeiou rotates to nrvbh

Comment: Add vowels, not replace words with vowels....

Comment: _"The 5 membered-syndicate are dangerous and efficient as well."_ can mean, only e and i (**e**ff**i**c**ie**nt) can be used. Others are (d**a**ng**e**r**ou**s). So, probably we need to add e and i to each part of the cryptext text and then do the rotation. May be then some anagrams from it. I could only find a word mneumonic somehow.